# error log and process automatically clear after app crash in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio-4.1

hello i update my `android studio` on `mac`

```
Android Studio 4.1
Build #AI-201.8743.12.41.6858069, built on September 23, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.15.7
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 2014M
Cores: 4
Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: org.jetbrains.kotlin
```

After update `Android Studio 4.1` i found issue in `Logcat`

> I Am Not Able To See My debuggable Process After App Crash in Logcat

whenever my App crash in Mobile that time new process is start is ok

but old debuggable process not displays in dropdown selection ....i cant track my crash or bug because of this

in attached screenshot process number :- 9018 is new process and old process is gone from dropdown

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set package filters in the Logcat to show the error messages for your app packages.

With the Logcat open, click on Edit Filter Configuration.
Then, fill out the Filter Name with the package name you want to filter. Next, add the Package Name and click OK.

The image below shows an example
[image]

And voila, it should now work without clearing your Logcat output.